# PrestaShop robots.txt and /module/ path indexing

Tags: seo, robots.txt, prestashop-1.7

friends. I have a question regarding PrestaShop off-the-shelf robots.txt file.

Is it a normal practice to allow Search engines to index PrestaShop `*/module/*` route?

Can please somebody comment: 
A) Does it works as expected? [ `*/module/*` indexation is necessary for the good SEO ]
, or
B) this is an issue - security breach, as Search engine is indexing PrestaShop internal technical structure and exposing it to the rest of the world?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the modules use "/module/" route for their front pages So it is a good idea to allow this on robots.txt file

But I do not recommend allowing the "/modules/" route as this can cause security problems for you

Comment: Are there some standard (pre-installed modules), that are using this path for the FO?
Can you please give some example. Thank you.

Comment: Some default modules like payment modules use this route but these pages are noindex and not important for SEO

Answer (score 0):

For SEO you need show crawlers only pages you believe are useful for users and you want user to find those content.

It means that if under */module/* you have pages with content you want user to see from search engine - you may open it in robots and make sure that there is no noindex tag in pages HTML.

Also note if you put */module/* to disallow, but you have inbound external links to pages in */module/*, those pages could be indexed by crawler despite of the fact you closed those pages in robots.